# If $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n - a_{n-2})=0$, prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(a_n - a_{n-1})}{n} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n - a_{n-2})=0$, prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(a_n - a_{n-1})}{n} = 0$.

I have no idea about solving it rigorously. I feel that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n - a_{n-1})=0$ holds true as well if all terms are positive or negative.

Comment: That last statement is not true. Suppose you have the sucesion $\{ a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n=1$ if $n$ is even and $a_n=2$ if $n$ is odd. Then it holds $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n-a_{n-2})=0$ (and also what you have to prove), but it doesn't hold $\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_n-a_{n-1})=0$.

Comment: [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)?

Comment: @rtybase I tried but it just gives $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+a_{n-1})/n=0$

Answer (score 6):

Denote, for $n\geq 0$,
$$
\delta_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} a_{n+2}-a_n
$$
so that by assumption $\lim_{n\to\infty} \delta_n =0$. We have, for all $n\geq 0$,
$$
a_{2n} = a_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (a_{2k+2}-a_{2k})
= a_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \delta_{2k}\,.
$$
Similarly,
$$
a_{2n-1} = a_1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (a_{2k+3}-a_{2k+1})
= a_1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \delta_{2k+1}\,.
$$
Therefore, for $n\geq1$,
$$
\frac{a_{2n}-a_{2n-1}}{2n}
= \frac{a_0-a_1}{2n} + \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\delta_{2k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\delta_{2k+1}}{2n}
= \frac{a_0-a_1}{2n} + \frac{\delta_{2n-2}}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(\delta_{2k}-\delta_{2k+1})
$$
The first two terms obviously converge to $0$ *(can you see why?)* so it remains to show the third does as well. This in turn follows from [Cesaro's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), as 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\delta_{2n}-\delta_{2n+1}) = 0-0 = 0.
$$
To summarize: we just showed
$$\boxed{
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{2n}-a_{2n-1}}{2n} = 0
}$$
Now, you can easily conclude the same for
$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{2n+1}-a_{2n}}{2n+1}
$, 
as $a_{2n+1}-a_{2n} = \delta_{2n-1}+a_{2n-1}-a_{2n}$.

Answer (score 2):

let's denote $a_{n-1}-a_{n}$ by $x_n$

Now given condition states that for any given $\epsilon>0$

|$a_{n}-a_{n-2}$|$<\epsilon$ for all n>N$\in \mathbb{N}$

|$a_{n}-a_{n-2}$|$\geq$||$a_n-a_{n-1}|-|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}||$

which means $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(|x_n|-|x_{n-1}|)=0$

by stolz ceasaro theorem lim $\frac{|x_n|}{n}$=0

I hope you will stich together these peices

Comment: As written this is clearly incorrect; consider e.g. the alternating sequence 1, 2, 1, 2, ... from the comments to the answer.Then your $x_n$ is simply $(-1)^n$ and has no limit; and the limit of its absolute value is not zero.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki check the correction  thanks for correcting

Comment: @PintuKumar I deleted my comment as I had misread what you had written. In the current form, it's basicalyl correct, although with missing details.

Comment: @ClementC. I have purposely missed the steps I think the reader will understand it better if he himself combine these steps

Comment: @PeterForeman Not an issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$0\le||a_n-a_{n-1}|-|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}||\le|a_n-a_{n-2}|$$
and also
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=0\tag{1}$$
Hence, by applying the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) and $(1)$, we get that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(|a_n-a_{n-1}|-|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n-a_{n-1}|-|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|}{n-(n-1)}=0$$
We can then apply the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) and $(1)$ to the above limit which directly gives
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{n}=0$$